# Prove that $2005$ devides $55555\dots$ with 800 5's

Tags: number-theory

I am trying to prove that $2005$ divides $55555\dots$ ( with 800 5's ). This basically reduces to proving that $401$, which is a prime, divides $1111\dots$ (with 800 1's) .

I know this revolves around Fermat's little theorem..but can't quite grasp it. Would you be so kind to provide me with a hint on how to solve this?

Comment: You only need to prove that $401$ divides $\sum\limits_{n=0}^{799}10^n$.

Answer (score 4):

$$\underbrace{55\cdots55}_{800\ 5\text{'s}}=5\cdot\dfrac{10^{800}-1}{10-1}$$

Now clearly this is divisible by $5$ as $(5,10-1)=1$

As $401$ is prime and $(10,401)=1$ by Fermat's Little theorem $10^{400}\equiv1\pmod{401}$

$\implies401$ divides $10^{800}-1=(10^{400}-1)(10^{400}+1)$

As $(10-1,401)=1,401$ will divide $$\dfrac{10^{800}-1}{10-1}$$

Comment: @Arthur, $$\underbrace{55}_{2\ 5\text{'s}}=5\cdot\dfrac{10^2-1}{10-1} $$

Comment: Yeah, that's what I realized. Damn off-by-one errors.