# Prove: $2005|\underbrace{5 5\cdots 5}_{800\text{ digits}}$

Tags: divisibility

$2005=5\cdot 401$

Divisibility by $5$ follows from the last digit of $\underbrace{5 5\cdots 5}_{800\text{ digits}}$.

How toprove divisibility by $401$?

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2014958/proove-that-2005-devides-55555-dots-with-800-5s

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your number is $5\left(\dfrac{10^{800} - 1}{9} \right)$

> $401$ is a prime number $\implies 10^{400} \equiv 1 \pmod{401}  \implies 10^{800} \equiv 1 \pmod{40}$
>
> $\implies 5\left( \dfrac{10^{800} - 1}{9} \right) \equiv 0 \pmod{401}$

Comment: I understand how you get that $10^{800}-1 \equiv 0 (mod 401)$ but I don't understand how you get that $\frac{10^{800}-1}{9} \equiv 0 (mod 401)$?

Comment: @stenvic 
9x is divisible to 401 => x is divisible to 401

Comment: do you mean $401\mid 9x \Rightarrow 401\mid x$?

Comment: You have to prove that the numerator is divisible by $9$.