# Prove that $2005|\underbrace{55 \ldots5}_{800\text{ digits}}$

Tags: discrete-mathematics, modular-arithmetic, divisibility

Prove that $2005|\underbrace{55 \ldots 5}_{800\text{ digits}}$

I know that $2005=5\cdot 401$ since $55 \ldots 5$ is divisibility with $5$ i only need to prove that $55 \ldots 5$ is divisibility with 401.

$55 \ldots 5=5(10^{799}+10^{798}+\cdots+10+1)$, then I can find a remainder for example $10^3\equiv198 \pmod {401}$ for $10^5\equiv151 \pmod {401}$, and put in sum and prove that sum $(10^{799}+10^{798}+\cdots+10+1)$ is divisibility with number $401$ but I it seem like bad idea, do you have something?

Comment: You should edit your post for clarity.  Presumably you meant $5\times (10^{800}-1)$ but it really isn't clear.

Comment: yes sorry for my notation

Comment: Note that $5^{800}$ is divisible only for $5^k$ with $0\le k \le 800$.

Comment: No problem.  To your question, note that $400$ divides $800$ so any divisor of $400$ is also a divisor of $800$...now ask yourself what the possible orders of $10$ are $\pmod {401}$.

Comment: it is not $5^{800}$

Comment: $55...5 = 5\frac{10^{800}-1}{10-1}$

Comment: Use the geometric series formula, the fact that 9 is coprime to 401, and Fermat's Little Theorem.

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2027055/prove-2005-underbrace5-5-cdots-5-800-text-digits?rq=1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since $401$ is a prime number, then, by Fermat's little theorem, $10^{400}\equiv1\pmod{401}$. So, $10^{800}\equiv1\pmod{401}$, which means that $401\mid10^{800}-1$. But $9(=10-1)\mid10^{88}-1$. so$$401\mid\frac{10^{800}-1}9\times9;$$since $\gcd(401,9)=1$, it follows from this that $401\mid\frac{10^{800}-1}9$. This is equivalent to the assertion $2\,005\mid\overbrace{55\ldots5}^{800\text{ times}}$.

Comment: $55...5 = 5\frac{10^{800}-1}{10-1}$ so $9*55...5/5 = (10^{800}-1)$. You have to use the fact that $401$ is prime to get the assertion.

Comment: @Stockfish Sure. I have been most helpful today. Thank you a lot.

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:** $$2005\,\big|\,\underbrace{55 \ldots 5}_{800\text{ digits}}$$
$$401\cdot5\,\big|\,(\underbrace{11 \ldots 1}_{800\text{ digits}})\cdot5$$

Answer (score 1):

Note that your number is
$5(10^{800}-1)/9
=5(10^{400}-1)(10^{400}+1)/9$
and then apply Fermat.

Comment: Thanks. Did it from my phone and didn't check as much as I should.

Answer (score 0):

Note that $5^{800}$ is divisible only by $5^k$ with $0\le k \le 800$ but

$$2005=5\cdot 401$$

and $401$ is prime.

Comment: I write that in my answer