# What will be the remainder when 111...(123 times) is divided by 271?

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory

How to do it? The number is quite big to apply basic theory.  Can anyone provide me a solution?

Comment: See http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2014958/proove-that-2005-devides-55555-dots-with-800-5s

Answer (score 2):

**Hint 1**: $11111 = 41 \cdot 271$.

> **Hint 2**: So $\underbrace{11111 \cdots 11111}_{120 \ \text{ones}}000$ is divisible by $271$.